# Image drag and drop activate scroll ListView (react-native)

Tags: listview, react-native, drag-and-drop

Currently I am trying to play around with PanResponder, and I have an idea making image as a draggable, and when user drag image at bottom of listview, the listview renderRow() will scroll as long the user did not change the position of the image.

Here is sample of what I want to do..
[image]

so far what I am doing just drag the image and it will return so same position after user release.

```js
constructor(props) {
  ....
  
  this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder : () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null,{
        dx: this.state.pan.x,
        dy: this.state.pan.y
      }]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
        Animated.spring(
          this.state.pan,
          {toValue:{x:0,y:0}}
        ).start();
      }
    });
}

renderDraggable(){
    if(this.state.showDraggable){
      return (
        <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
          <Animated.View 
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}                       
            style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), styles.circle]}>
            <Text>Drag me!</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  
renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
render() {
  return(
  <View style={styles.list}>
    <ListView
      dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(optionsArray[this.state.question].answerArr)}
              renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
      {this.renderDraggable()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Thanks! Hope anyone can guide and point me to right direction..

Answer (score 0):

found the way!

put ref inside ListView

```js
<ListView
              ref={ ref => this.listview = ref}
              dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(optionsArray[this.state.question].answerArr)}
              renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            />
```

then onPanResponderMove I just need to call the listViewScrollTo, but to ensure the Drag me Circle also move I need to wrap inside (e,gesture) and since animated.event will not work, I just need to put (e,gesture) immediately after animated.event.

```js
 onPanResponderMove: (e, gesture) => {
        this.listview.scrollTo({ y: this.state.heightList+200 });
        Animated.event([null,{
          dx: this.state.pan.x,
          dy: this.state.pan.y,
        }])(e, gesture);
      }
```

anyone have another solution can share since Im not sure it's the best way to do this.

tQ